# Fragments not allowing button or activity behavior

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I have a main activity that starts up when the app opens. Once the activity is started, it then opens a GridView fragment from the main activity onCreate(Also, the main activity and fragment share the same XML layout).

The problem I am having is that whenever I try to add a onClick event to my Button, nothing happens unless I remove the code that opens up the GridView's fragment from my main activity.

NOTE: I am using fragments for my GridView because I am displaying lots of images at the same time, so I've set up Fragment classes to handle them efficiently without it effecting performance.

Would there be any way around this?, cheers in advance.

Main activity:

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final String TAG = "ImageGridActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.image_grid_fragment);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Utils.enableStrictMode();

    //Whenever I remove this code here:
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, new ImageGridFragment(), TAG);
        ft.commit();

    //To here, it works

    Button B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            Log.w("myApp", "no network");

        }
    });

}
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    style="@style/PhotoGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing" >
</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As you have the same layout for the activity and for the fragment, the click listener will be set on the button(but this will be from the activity layout) but as you add the fragment that button will be covered by the fragment's layout so you'll not get click events. Or, I hope you aren't trying to set the click listener on the button from the fragment layout.

Comment: @Luksprog No, I'm trying to set the Click event from the main layout as you can see here. What could I do to fix this problem I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to set the Click event from the main layout as you can see
>   here. What could I do to fix this problem I have?

You'll never interact with the `Button` from the activity layout because you add the `Fragment` directly on the `FrameLayout` which holds the content, so the fragment will cover the previously set content of the `Activity`. You could modify the activity layout like this:

**R.layout.act_ImageGridActivity.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

followed by using the above `FrameLayout` when doing the fragment transaction:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.frag_container, new ImageGridFragment(), TAG);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would it be easier to define the button in the actual fragment of the GridView?

Comment: @Jack It depends on how you plan to use the fragment. If the fragment will stay there for the life of the activity then you could define it in the fragment's layout. But, if you want to handle the click event at the activity level it would be a bit harder to do it because you can't just use `findViewById` with a view from a fragment that was just set in a transaction(the transaction will happen asynchronously, some time in the future after the current main UI event is done(like onCreate finishing)).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and help, this has helped me greatly. Have a nice day :)